# CSS: right label with float left wraps under zoom

Tags: html, css, forms, word-wrap

I have a form with `legend` and `fieldset`s, and need to have `label`s by left side of `input`s.

I want to stylish my `form` `label`s with CSS only, but CSS selectors cannot find preceding siblings, so I need to write `label` after `input` in HTML code in order to select the `label`s connected with invalid `input`s, and use `float: left`.

When `input` is filled incorrectly, corresponding label needs to be changed.
In following examples the label becomes red and validation fail description message unfolds.

Description `label` needs to be on the same line as corresponding input (for aesthetic purposes) or, at least, left corner should be aligned by the most right point of the `input`.

The problem occurs when I try to zoom in.
I emulate this by setting lower width to the outer `div`.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

fieldset {}

section {}

input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 80px;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid+label {
  color: red;
}

input[type="text"]+label+label {
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid+label+label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.field-row {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fieldset</legend>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div class="field-row">
            <input id="first" type="text" value="" required />
            <label for="first">First</label>
            <label>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="field-row">
            <input id="second" type="text" value="" />
            <label for="second">Second</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

On this snippet you can see that the first row is very wide and goes out of outer `fieldset` (at least in Google Chrome).
If I use `overflow: auto` for the `fieldset`, `legend` text moves left when I move scrollbar.

When required `input` is valid, corresponding `label` goes to another row, but I need the `label` to be on one line with connected `input`.

The hack, which helped me, is to set `min-width` of the `field-row` block wider than `label` + `input` width.
Though, this needs to know maximum allowed width of them and either use `JavaScript` or change it on any `padding`, `margin` and `width` changes of dependent fields.

Also it works well when I don't use `float`.
Although, this approach will need to use `JavaScript` to change change `label` in `input` validation state changed.

I make a `ReactJS` application, so `JavaScript` is not a problem,
but I want to investigate and use CSS capabilities as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to support modern browsers, I recommend giving up on trying to use float for this and use flexbox instead.

All you need to do is to make the `.field-row` div `display: flex;` and then set the `order` property for the input and label elements. Like this:

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

fieldset {}

section {}

input[type="text"] {
  order: 2;
}

input[type="text"]+label {
  text-align: right;
  order: 1;
  width: 80px;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid+label {
  color: red;
}

input[type="text"]+label+label {
  display: none;
  order: 3;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid+label+label {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
}

.field-row {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fieldset</legend>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div class="field-row">
            <input id="first" type="text" value="" required />
            <label for="first">First</label>
            <label>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="field-row">
            <input id="second" type="text" value="" />
            <label for="second">Second</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've seen, that `order` has some issues in Safari 10, but, I guess, it should not affect this case.